# What is the best way to pass information from one steps def class to another?

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Injecting one Steps def into another can rapidly lead to dependency bloat as the amount of re-use among steps defs grows. Furthermore it couples steps defs very tightly to each-other.

There must be a better way. Any suggestions?

Is passing information between steps defs an anti-pattern that should be avoided anyway?

Comment: for me an `abstractStepDefClass` whis is extended by all step defs and includes all common steps has done the trick

Comment: @Dude I agree with him at minium level. Cucumber is not design to support 100% OOPS. It is simple When/And and Then

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about sharing state between different Step Definition classes, you can do this with Dependency Injection frameworks like Spring.
Here's a blog that explains (better than I could paraphrase right here):
http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/06/24/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-spring

If you don't want to use Spring, there are other DI frameworks you can use.