# Best way to reference a variable in all classes?

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

So, I am learning Java, coming from Ruby and Python.  I am writing selenium tests using WebDriver and cucumber, and this is basically what I have now:

CommonSteps.java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class CommonSteps {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
```

LoginSteps.java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LoginSteps {

    WebDriver driver = CommonSteps.driver;

    @When("^a thing happens$")
    public void a_thing_happens() {
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Since I know that `beforeScenario()` will always be called before each test, and that method is in the CommonSteps file, I declare it as a class variable there, and create a local variable at the top of other step classes to use in those steps.  But since I'm just now learning java, is there a better way to do this?  I am trying to adhere to best practices and make this as user friendly and scalable as possible.  Thanks!

Comment: If it needs to be scalable, don't make the `driver` `static`. What you need is dependency injection. Take the `driver` as a parameter in the constructor, or in a setter. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3334578/5743988) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21218868/5743988).

Comment: Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573676/sharing-same-selenium-webdriver-between-step-definition-files/31579738#31579738) could help you

Comment: Also this (Di & Cucumber): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713674/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-information-from-one-steps-def-class-to-another